# Watson IoT Platform and IBM Blockchain: No fabrics are configured for your organization

Tags: watson-iot

I am trying to link my Watson IoT Platform with IBM Blockchain on Bluemix instance. In the Watson IoT Platform Extensions page, in the Blockchain tile, I click Setup and fill in Fabric information as per the instruction available here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/blockchain/dev_blockchain.html#iotblockchain_link

As requested, I noted down following service credentials:
 Peer information: api_host and api_port_tls
 User of type 1 (client) information: username and secret

I also made sure that the user that I select must not be previously registered with a peer other than the peer that I selected.

However, my IBM Blockchain instance never gets discovered by my Watson IoT instance. I always receive "No fabrics are configured for your organization." in Configure Blockchain pane.

Any help with the above would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to check your fabric details.  Here is an example of a correctly formatted configuration:
Name: my_fabric
Host: 01234567890123456789-vp2.us.blockchain.ibm.com
Port: 5001
User ID: user_type1_0
Secret Key: 0123456789
Use TLS?: On (slide to the right)

Use TLS must be on for IBM Blockchain fabrics. Check your fabric in Bluemix using the dashboard and make sure all your peers are working properly. You can also try a different user (e.g. user_type1_1 and corresponding secret) or a different peer in the same fabric. The user you specify does not have to be already enrolled with the fabric.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks :) I realized that what is needed first is to activate blockchain extension and then configure it (and not the other way round like the tutorial on Bluemix would suggest).